# What about adding info from other answers in to my own answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

If person A gives an answer, and then person B gives a different answer, is it okay for person A to edit their own answer and add a summary/condensed version of person B's answer?

Example:

Person A: "The maximum current draw should be 5A because the inductors are rated [XYZ]. Be aware that this will be less if the ambient temperature is higher than 30C"

Person B: "Your circuit does not have the recommended ground plane area for the MOSFETs. The datasheet says [X mm^2], you have [Y mm^2].

Can/should Person A mention the ground plane issue? It seems like "stealing".

Comment: This has been asked on a [very old main meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21643/an-elegant-solution-for-answer-stealing-edits) (but from the point of view of the person being "stolen")

Comment: @dim Oh, I forgot there was a generic meta.SE, my question perhaps doesn't belong here?

Comment: Not necessarily. Sometimes, the usages/rules vary depending on the sites, so the answers here may lead to a different consensus. Honestly, I don't know. I just think this main meta post is relevant, but my comment wasn't intended to invalidate your question (especially given the age of this main meta post I linked to).

Answer (score 1):

`Can/should Person A mention the ground plane issue?`

Yes, if they expand on it. If all you are doing is copy/pasting/rephrasing, then you are wasting everyones time.

In your example, expanding that the recommended ground plane is for X temperature and Y current, or why the manufacturer came up with that number would be beneficial to everybody.

If all you are doing is saying "don't forget to make sure you have the right copper size", your not helping.

Then again, the goal is to have the most concise yet complete answer in a single spot. But people frown upon that type of unattributed copying.

If you happen, due to time, both have the same information, don't worry about being called a copy, it happens. Many people here have overlapping knowledge and double posts happen. But if you come back a day later to add basically what the other guy just said, it doesn't pass the sniff test.

Comment: If you expand on something in another post, you might say something like *"As JohnDoe said, your ground plane is too small.  To figure out what it should be, ..."*.